# Hypotheses that imply total categoricity

Tags: logic, model-theory

Some theories are totally categorical.

Are there some hypotheses that do imply the total categoricity of a theory?

Comment: Note that actually the theory of vector spaces (over $\mathbb{Q}$, say) is **not** totally categorical: it is *uncountably* categorical, but it has infinitely many countable models, indexed by dimension.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114069/characterization-of-totally-categorical-theories

Comment: @Noah: In fact over any infinite field. But it will be totally categorical over a finite field, once you add the assumption there are infinitely many vectors. I guess you can fix the countable case by adding the schema that says that no finitely many vectors span the whole space.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually, you still run into problems. How do you express span? There are two basic approaches for talking about vector spaces in model theory: as two-sorted structures (scalars and vectors) or as one-sorted structures (vectors only, with each scalar being given a separate unary function symbol). In the latter case, you can't quantify over scalars so we can't really talk about spanning at all; in the former case, your scalar part itself has to also be totally categorical, so $\mathbb{Q}$ still doesn't work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not look for a complete characterization, just for some sufficient condition. (I have already seen that question).

Comment: To the OP: note that the theory of vector spaces over a fixed finite field is not complete, you really want to talk about the theory of *infinite* vector spaces over a fixed finite field. But this is a minor point. (Also, note that the finite field has to be fixed.)

Comment: @Noah: Right. That's a good point. Just work in $\cal L_{\infty,\infty}$, then. :P

Comment: For a complete theory in a countable language with infinite models, $\aleph_0$ categoricity + $\aleph_1$ categoricity gives total categoricity.  This is of course Morley's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments, dav11 suggests $\aleph_0$-categorical + $\aleph_1$ categorical, by Morley's theorem. Using the Baldwin-Lachlan characterization of uncountably categorical theories, totally categorical is also equivalent to $\aleph_0$-categorical + $\omega$-stable + no Vaughtian pairs.

For a sufficient condition that encompasses the case of infinite-dimensional vector spaces over a finite field, you might like strongly minimal + locally finite.

*Strongly minimal* means that for any model $M$, any definable subset of $M$ is finite or cofinite.

*Locally finite* means that $\mathrm{acl}(A)$ is finite whenever $A$ is finite.

Why is this sufficient? If $T$ is strongly minimal, then already it is $\aleph_1$-categorical. And in a strongly minimal theory, there is a unique non-algebraic type over any set. So if $\mathrm{acl}(A)$ is finite, then there are only finitely many $1$-types over $A$ (the types of the elements of $\mathrm{acl}(A)$ together with the unique non-algebraic type). So there are finitely many $1$-types over every finite set, which is equivalent to $\aleph_0$-categoricity.

Answer (score 0):

A countable theory is uncountably categorical if and only if it is $\omega$-stable and has no Vaughtian pairs, and it is $\aleph_0$-categorical if and only if $S_n(\emptyset)$ is finite for every $n$.

I don't recall any alternative description of having no Vaughtian pairs, but I believe $\omega$-stable $\omega$-categorical theories can be alternatively described as those for which $S_1(A)$ is finite or countable whenever $A$ is finite or countable (respectively).